# Access android internal storage for full passive deep malware scan?

Tags: malware, android, forensics, antimalware

Is it possible to passively (with a computer) view/scan **all** content on an android mobile device's internal storage without crackopen/damaging it? For a deep malware scan of the whole storage of the device?

---

For example: Making a 100% duplicate copy of the internal storage (especially the system path and folders) for examination on a computer?

Consider the user knows all his passwords and PINs and the android filesystem is compromised with malware that would hide itself if tested with an on-device anti-virus application. Thats why I'm asking for **passive** scan technique. Like you can create a 100% duplicate image of your harddrive from computer.